# How do we get all property values from a JSON with name ID but has a specific parent object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a JSOn with multiple id value and I need to get an array out of all id values with parent 'parent4'

I did this and it returns me all id values in an array

```
function findAllByKey(obj, keyToFind) {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce(
      (acc, [key, value]) =>
        key === keyToFind
          ? acc.concat(value)
          : typeof value === "object"
          ? acc.concat(findAllByKey(value, keyToFind))
          : acc,
      []
    );
  }
```

But I just need those IDs with parent 'parent4'
My output should be `['this is needed1', 'this is needed2', 'this is needed3', 'this is needed4']`

Here is the codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-noyce-0jgzj0?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm mostly making use of your own code here.
First look for the parents you need:

```
const resultParent = findAllByKey(myObj, "parent4");
```

Then input the result and get the ids you are looking for:

```
const result = findAllByKey(resultParent, "@id");
```

And then:
`console.log(result)` will output: `["this is needed1", "this is needed2", "this is needed3", "this is needed4"]`